# Bitmap spatial distortion: optimizing indirect array access

Tags: c, optimization, bitmap, android-ndk, neon

I have developed some bitmap processing routines for ARM processors in C using the NDK and SIMD NEON assembly in the inner loop.

The structure is as follows:

```
for (row=0;row<height;row++){

      src = &bitmap_src[row*width];
      dst = &bitmap_dst[row*width];

      // other pointers initting for the asm part....
      color = &color_array[row*width];
      light = &light_array[row*width];

      __asm volatile(

          // Optimized Neon assembly code. Process a row
          // makes use of src, dst, color and light pointers  

      );

}
```

I am happy with the results achieved, and is much faster than a plain C version (which I use as a reference)
Now I want to do some kind of spatial distortion to the bitmaps before doing the same processing.
To do this mapping I use another array P[], in such a way that (if we don't do the inner processing)

```
bitmap_dest[row*width + col ] = bitmap_src[ P[row*width + col ] ];
```

As I need linear memory access for the NEON part, I precalculated each row:

```
unsigned int PP[width];  // temporary "mapped" row

for (row=0;row<height;row++){

      for (col =0; col<width; col++){
        //PP[col]=bitmap_src[ P[row*width + col] ];
        PP[col]=bitmap_src[*(P++)];  //both lines do the same. This is faster
      }
      src = &PP[0]; //now the source points to the mapped row instead of the original.
      dst = &bitmap_dst[row*width];

      // other pointers initting for the asm part....
      color = &color_array[row*width];
      light = &light_array[row*width];

      __asm volatile(

          // Optimized Neon assembly code. Process a row
          // makes use of src, dst, color and light pointers  

      );

}
```

It is still much faster than an old version that I had totally writen in plain C, but twice slower than the first.

As I suppose that the speed drop is due mainly to cache misses, if I used direct mapping instead of reverse, I would have

bitmap_dest[ P2[row*width + col] ] = bitmap_src[ row*width + col ];

this would allow me to still load the source linearly, but would have to change the store part and don't know if it would be worth. Also, as the mapping is not necessarily bijective, I would lose resolution.

So my question is: knowing that indirect array access is expensive, but still making use of this structure, are there tips to optimize it?